# Execute Selenium Commands on a Browser that is already open

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am looking for an example code that will allow me to run Selenium commands against a browser that is already open.

Typically when you start testing with Selenium it opens a new instance of the browser. But I am looking
for a solution where you would run the script and it will just start executing its codes on whatever browser and tab is currently visible.

Is that possible?

Comment: Not with selenium..what is your actual requirement of testing?

Comment: Do you mean reusing the same instance of driver (running tests in the same browser not opening new browser)?

Comment: Hi. No I meant I will open the browser manually and when I run my tests it will simply run the commands on the current tab (similar to iMacros for Firefox).

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge this is not possible with selenium.

You have to open browser during the test script only otherwise it won't be able to identify or capture already opened browser's object.

Answer (score 0):

No its not. There is an [old issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18) still open since 2009.